# ERROR unrecognized command: juju generate-config

Tags: juju

Currently I'm trying to create a charm with my software for juju version 2(develop). I've installed packages **juju_2.0-beta1-0ubuntu1~15.10.1~juju1_all.deb**, **juju-core2_2.0-beta1-0ubuntu1~15.10.1~juju1_amd64.deb**, and **juju-local**.

But when I'm trying to set up local environment(or model as it called now), I receive next error:

```
$ juju generate-config
ERROR unrecognized command: juju generate-config
```

Other commands working fine:

```
$ juju version
2.0-beta1-wily-amd64
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command you're trying to run `generate-config` is not available in Juju 2.0, only in the 1.x series. A similar command is coming but hasn't yet landed. For now, you can find all the information you need to set up Juju here: https://jujucharms.com/docs/devel/getting-started

Comment: Thanks for answer! But how can I set up juju2 for local testing now? I'm unable to deploy it to cloud providers now.

Comment: With juju 2 the 'local provider' has been discontinued and in place it's using LXD. There are no official release notes as this process is still under heavy development and in the future you should consult the official docs but for now you can follow the instructions in the beta release notes here: https://jujucharms.com/docs/devel/temp-release-notes#lxd-provider