# Configuring juju for MAAS 2.0

Tags: 16.04, juju, maas, openstack

I'm trying to understand cloud architecture better and decided to setup a private cloud using ubuntu 16.04.

I found this (seemingly) nice guide on setting up a private cloud using MAAS, juju and openstack, and managed to get through the first step of setting up MAAS and connecting some nodes.

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/clouddocs/en/Intro.html?_ga=1.56396459.1002047384.1448462651

Now I've proceeded to setup juju, and hit a snag at the following step:

```
Configuring Juju to work with MAAS
3. Edit the Juju environments.yaml file
```

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/clouddocs/en/Installing-Juju.html

It seems that the version of juju (2.0-beta15-xenial-amd64) that ubuntu 16.04 grabs no longer has the 'generate_config' command.  I've started following this [guide](https://jujucharms.com/docs/devel/getting-started) mentioned in a response to a question about the 'generate_config' issue, but this is not MAAS specific.

[ERROR unrecognized command: juju generate-config](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741928/error-unrecognized-command-juju-generate-config)

At the moment, I've gone through the steps up to and including executing the `sudo lxd init` command.  However, in attempting to run the `juju bootstrap lxd-precrime localhost` command as described in the guide, but now I'm getting the following errors:

```
$ juju bootstrap lxd-precrime localhost 
ERROR cannot find network interface "lxdbr0": route ip+net: no such network interface 
ERROR invalid config: route ip+net: no such network interface
```

Do I need to continue with this step if I want to integrate `juju` with `MAAS`, or is there a way to continue to integrate with `MAAS` without resolving this *networking* issue?

Answer (score 2):

The guide on help.ubuntu.com is for juju < 2.0.

Re lxd error, did you follow the entire getting-started guide?

The above guide sets up a "cloud" based on LXD, not MAAS.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, my problem was that I needed to first assign an 'network' properly to the 'Ready' nodes.

After assigning the network the next problem was 'no storage defined'.  This was resolve by re-commissioning (after setting the network) and manually power cycling the nodes.